# Concatenating all columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate all columns of a pandas dataframe so that I end up with 1 column that contains all the values from the dataframe. The following code does this:

```
df2 = pd.concat([df[0], df[1], df[2], df[3], df[4], df[5], df[6], df[7]])
```

But I would like to be able to do this with dataframes that have different numbers of columns. When I tried:

`dfpr2 = pd.concat([df.columns)`

I get the following error:
"cannot concatenate object of type `<class 'pandas.core.indexes.range.RangeIndex>`; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid

is there a way to get around this? I tried setting ignore_index = True, but that did not seem to help either. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

```
Timing for different methods : 

%timeit df.iloc[:,0].str.cat(df.iloc[:,1:].astype(str),',')
880 µs ± 28.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit df.astype(str).agg('|'.join,axis=1)
1.45 ms ± 39 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit df.astype(str).sum(axis=1)
562 µs ± 11.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit [','.join(ent) for ent in df.astype(str).to_numpy()]
350 µs ± 6.48 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

I think @cs95 has a stackoverflow post that talked about strings. for strings, they are much faster when the computation is done within Python.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC `df.astype(str).sum(axis=1)`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['A','B','C'],
             'B' : [0,1,2],
             'C' : ['2019-01-10','2020-01-10','2021-01-10']})

df['hash'] = df.astype(str).sum(axis=1)

print(df)

   A  B           C          hash
0  A  0  2019-01-10  A02019-01-10
1  B  1  2020-01-10  B12020-01-10
2  C  2  2021-01-10  C22021-01-10
```

If you need a custom delimiter  then use `.agg`

```
df.astype(str).agg('|'.join,axis=1)

0    A|0|2019-01-10
1    B|1|2020-01-10
2    C|2|2021-01-10
```

Comment: Quick question: how to combine `sum` with a delimiter?

Comment: Awesome, cheers. Though I have a feeling `agg` is not as performant as `sum`

Comment: @MarkWang string methods are usually slow but I agree, agg will be slower than `sum` but I haven't tested it usually you want to concat all columns to create some sort of surrogate key so it's a hit you have to take to update tables

Comment: -1. This isn't what the OP asked. They need to get a single column that contains all rows of all the columns in the dataframe, one below the other. This just merges all the cells in a row into a single string

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple way of concatenating column values

```
df1 = df['1st Column Name'] + df['2nd Column Name'] + ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You where on the right track. The problem is `df.columns` doesn't actually contain `Series` of data, but an `Index` of all the columns

Instead, you can still use `df.columns` inside a generator that returns all the columns `Series` and then concatenate them:

```
s = pd.concat((df[col] for col in df.columns))
```

Note that the resulting `s` is of type `Series`. If you need a `DataFrame`, you can use the following line

```
df2 = s.to_frame()
```